# what happens to a car that hasn't been driven for 3years?

Tags: jeep

I'm hoping that I'll soon be the owner of 4.0l turbo charged, 4wd 1994 jeep cherokee that's been sat in a garage, undriven for 3years. but i don't know what to start with during the reviving process

Comment: Dry rot, rust, battery low/no charge, etc...

Answer (score 4):

In no particular order:

- Clean the fuel tank and fuel filter.
- Do a full oil change (engine, transmission, diffs).
- Change the brake fluid.
- Check the condition of the plugs, plug leads and battery.
- Check the condition of the wheel bearings.
- Check the condition of the tyres.
- Check the condition of the timing belt, auxiliary belts and pulleys.

After that, you'll have to go by any weird symptoms.

Comment: Id also have a close look at the tyres to ensure they haven't perished, cracked or split.  And check the battery acid levels.

Comment: well i had an accident since then i never used it so i have to buy a new battery and tires too cause they all flat, and to top it all have to buy some few engine parts like the pulls and fan belt

Comment: I should probably add those to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

What happens? Depending upon exposure to the elements, sun/rain and climate the car will deteriorate. The more extreme the environment/climate the faster things expire.

Tyres go flat.
Rubber perishes (tyres, wiper blades)
Fuel goes off.
Grease hardens. 
Oil breaks down.
Any raw metal parts not covered in oil/grease could rust/corrode.
Batteries die. 
Electrical contacts corrode.

Was the Jeep stored inside? Under a cover? Extreme environment? Sun/Salt/Snow?

Comment: environment a bit sunny and i covered it on the front mirror just to avoid water dripping in the dash board and i am from east Africa Tanzania  the weather isn't that bad

Comment: Rust on the internal components of the engine, gear box, transfer case, etc.... is something to check for.  These surfaces all are unpainted and once the oil drains away are unprotected.